# Using a composite key in a many-to-many relationship in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, database-design, jpa

I've got the following situation:

- A User object has a Set of Permission objects (`Set<Permission>`)
- Each User can have zero or more Permissions
- A Permission object has three fields
- The three fields of Permission make up the composite
  key for that permission.
- As a consequence of this, we want exactly
  one instance in the DB of each Permission.  Each user can potentially
  have the same Permission.
- The User object therefore has a
  many-to-many relationship with Permission.

The question is: how, in this situation, do I make the Permission entity a composite key of itself? I'm particularly interested in doing this in the context of this many-to-many relationship.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***1º*** A Permission object has three fields

***2º*** The three fields of Permission up make up the composite key

Both property and compound primary keys **share the same columns**

So Your question looks like this one

```
@Entity
public class Permission {

    private PermissionId permissionId;

    private Integer field1;
    private Integer field2;
    private Integer field3;

    // required no-arg constructor   
    public Permission() {}

    public Permission(Integer field1, Integer field2, Integer field3) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;

        setPermissionId(new PermissonId(Integer field1, Integer field2, Integer field3));
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public PermissionId getPermissionId() {
        return this.permissionId;
    }

    @Column(name="FIELD_1", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public Integer getField1() {
        return this.field1;
    }

    @Column(name="FIELD_2", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public Integer getField2() {
        return this.field2;
    }

    @Column(name="FIELD_3", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public Integer getField3() {
        return this.field3;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class PermissionId implements Serializable {

        private Integer field1;
        private Integer field2;
        private Integer field3;

        // required no-arg constructor
        public PermissionId() {}

        public PermissionId(Integer field1, Integer field2, Integer field3) {
            this.field1 = field1;
            this.field2 = field2;
            this.field3 = field3;
        }

        @Column(name="FIELD_1", nullable=false)
        public Integer getField1() {
            return this.field1;
        }

        @Column(name="FIELD_2", nullable=false)
        public Integer getField2() {
            return this.field2;
        }

        @Column(name="FIELD_3", nullable=false)
        public Integer getField3() {
            return this.field3;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if(o == null) 
                return false;

            if(!(o instanceof PermissionId))
                return false;

            final PermissionId other = (PermissionId) o;

            if(!(getField1().equals(other.getField1()))) 
                return false;

            if(!(getField2().equals(other.getField2()))) 
                return false;

            if(!(getField3().equals(other.getField3()))) 
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        // requered hashcode impl
        public int hashcode() {
            // code goes here     
        }

    }

}
```

But do not forget

> Because **more than one property share the same column**, you have to define one of them as insertable=false, updatable=false. Otherwise, Hibernate will complain some errors.

And

> When you have a compound primary key, you have to set up its values. Hibernate does not support automatic generation of compound primary key.

**But** if you do not like the approach as shown above, you can do the following one

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PermissionId.class)
public class Permission {

    private Integer field1;
    private Integer field2;
    private Integer field3;

    // required no-arg constructor   
    public Permission() {}

    public Permission(Integer field1, Integer field2, Integer field3) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="FIELD_1", nullable=false)
    public Integer getField1() {
        return this.field1;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="FIELD_2", nullable=false)
    public Integer getField2() {
        return this.field2;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="FIELD_3", nullable=false)
    public Integer getField3() {
        return this.field3;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class PermissionId implements Serializable {

        private Integer field1;
        private Integer field2;
        private Integer field3;

        // required no-arg constructor
        public PermissionId() {}

        public PermissionId(Integer field1, Integer field2, Integer field3) {
            this.field1 = field1;
            this.field2 = field2;
            this.field3 = field3;
        }

        @Column(name="FIELD_1")
        public Integer getField1() {
            return this.field1;
        }

        @Column(name="FIELD_2")
        public Integer getField2() {
            return this.field2;
        }

        @Column(name="FIELD_3")
        public Integer getField3() {
            return this.field3;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if(o == null) 
                return false;

            if(!(o instanceof PermissionId))
                return false;

            final PermissionId other = (PermissionId) o;

            if(!(getField1().equals(other.getField1()))) 
                return false;

            if(!(getField2().equals(other.getField2()))) 
                return false;

            if(!(getField3().equals(other.getField3()))) 
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        // requered hashcode impl
        public int hashcode() {
            // code goes here     
        }

    }

}
```

regards,